# regular expression with space

Tags: regex, r

I am using regular expression in R with the following code:

```
> temp <- c("Herniorrhaphy, left inguinal", "Herniorrhaphy, right inguinal")
> grep("Herniorrhaphy, [left|right] inguinal",temp)
integer(0)
> grep("Herniorrhaphy, [left inguinal|right inguinal]",temp)
[1] 1 2
```

I wonder why the two regular expression give difference result, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want brackets `(` `)` not character class `[` `]`, ie

```
"Herniorrhaphy, (left|right) inguinal"
"Herniorrhaphy, (left inguinal|right inguinal)"
```

Answer (score 3):

According to regexp explanation in the documentation (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html):

> Note that alternation does not work
>   inside character classes, where | has
>   its literal meaning.

That explains why the first alternative doesn't return any results because '[' and ']' characters denote a character class. The correct sytax should be:

```
grep("Herniorrhaphy, (left|right) inguinal",temp)
```

On my R, the second alternative also returns empty set as well:

```
> temp <- c("Herniorrhaphy, left inguinal", "Herniorrhaphy, right inguinal")
> grep("Herniorrhaphy, [left inguinal|right inguinal] inguinal",temp)
integer(0)
>
```

Are you sure you are copying directly from the workspace?